# JaCoCo Debug Coverage Test Report

Tags: android, jenkins, jacoco, spoon, test-coverage

I have a problem when test android to create coverage test report. I use ./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport command to create coverage report. Report is created but result of all tests are %0. First device is rooted but second device isn't. We use these two devices to test with spoon and look spoon output. So these two devices use together. Problem: When we run this command with first device(rooted device) all coverage tests result is created as expected but when we run tests with two devices together all coverage results are %0. How can I solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JaCoCo works only on rooted devices or emulator.

See reference here [How do I get a jacoco coverage report using Android gradle plugin 0.10.0 or higher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795595/how-do-i-get-a-jacoco-coverage-report-using-android-gradle-plugin-0-10-0-or-high)

> Tip :
>   Since you can only get a coverage report with the emulator and device with root permission