# Classes in bundle 'app' do not match with execution data - Android

Tags: gradle, jacoco, dagger-hilt, jacoco-plugin, android-jacoco

Although similar questions are already present on internet, but I am unable to find any solution to this problem with regards to android platform. My project has multiple product flavors, uses kotlin and hilt. I believe byte code transformation while compiling the project is the root cause of disrupture.

I first thought probably Hilt is injecting code inside classes, therefore I made sure to copy classes before Hilt tasks execution into a separate folder, then use those classes as source for jacoco. But it didn't work.

#### Error

```
[ant:jacocoReport] Classes in bundle 'app' do not match with execution data. For report generation the same class files must be used as at runtime.
[ant:jacocoReport] Execution data for class com/company/myapp/Data$callApi$1 does not match.
[ant:jacocoReport] Execution data for class com/company/myapp/factory/SomeFactory$SomeGenerator does not match.
```

and the list continues for whole bunch of classes in the app. Due to these errors, **code coverage is always zero** although there are bunch of unit test already written in the app.

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    def hiltTaskPattern = ~/\bhilt.*\w+FlavorADebug\b/

    def tasksList = getSubprojects()
            .collect { it.tasks }
            .flatten()

    def copyFilesTask = tasksList.find { it.name == "copyClassFilesForJacoco" }

    if (copyFilesTask != null) {
        tasksList.findAll { hiltTaskPattern.matcher(it.name).matches() }
                .each { it.dependsOn copyFilesTask }
    }
}

task copyClassFilesForJacoco(dependsOn: "compileDebugJavaWithJavac", type: Copy) {

    def javaDebugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/flavorADebug/classes", excludes: androidFilesExcluded)
    def kotlinDebugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/flavorADebug", excludes: androidFilesExcluded)

    from javaDebugTree, kotlinDebugTree
    into layout.buildDirectory.dir(classFilesPathForInstrumentation)

    doLast {
        println("Files copied to ${classFilesPathForInstrumentation}")
    }
}
```

Then in the testCoverage task of type `JacocoReport`, `classDirectories` point out to copied files

Also, [kotlinx-kover](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-kover) seemed interesting, but it's in pre-mature state and lacks support of multiple product flavors along with outdated documentation which makes its usage unfavourable.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31916686/437146) answer explains very well reason for the problem, and also provide potential solution. But it is old, and not applicable to android project since it uses java plugin and jacoco-ant agent which is not compatible with android.

Can someone guide towards potential solutions for the aforementioned problem? TIA

Comment: did you got any solution for this now?

Comment: Nope, I wasn't able to continue over the test coverage that time due to some reason