# Integrating JaCoCo with Sonar for integration test coverage in Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco, sonar-runner, integration-testing

Has anyone tried to integrate JaCoCo with Sonar for integration test coverage in Android?

My project contains two modules:

- android library module (`library`),
- android module with instrumentation tests for `library` (`library-integration-tests`).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23965581/2880437) I found out that it is quite easy to generate JaCoCo test report for instrumentation tests, by adding:

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
           testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
```

to `build.gradle` of `library-integration-tests` and running `./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport`. However I end up with empty coverage report. It works fine, when instrumentation tests are in the same module - the report is generated correctly then.

Although `./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport` does not generate any `.exec` file, which is required by Sonar.

Gradle version: 2.2.1

JaCoCo version: 0.7.1.201405082137

Any help will be appreciated.