# How do I do Android tests with coverage in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: android, unit-testing

'Android tests' means tests with emulator.
I see the way to run JUnit tests with coverage, but there is no such option for Android tests.

Comment: Have you tried setting up Jacoco?

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795595/how-do-i-get-a-jacoco-coverage-report-using-android-gradle-plugin-0-10-0-or-high

Comment: It is a part of an answer. Is there a way to see coverage in Intellij IDEA?