# How to generate code coverage reports for Android unit tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, code-coverage

I'd like to start generating unit test code coverage reports for my Android application, where the unit tests are not in the `androidTest` folder, but in a `test` folder that I've created. To start, I've added the following to my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildTypes {
    ...
    debug {
        debuggable true
        testCoverageEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

Running `./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport` generates reports for my tests in the `androidTest` folder, but nothing in the `test` folder. How can I create those same coverage reports for the tests in the `test` folder?

Comment: Did you find a solution to that problem ? I have the same problem and I was about to investigate it further ? If by chance you found something in-between...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've founded answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23965581/1775228
Basically, you add to your gradle file:

```
debug {
    testCoverageEnabled true
}
```

and

```
android {
    jacoco {
        version = '0.7.9'
    }
}
```

After that run

```
./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport
```

in terminal and report will be generated in

```
/build/reports/coverage/debug
```

in your app folder/module. It worked for me.

---

For latest version and updates regarding changes read [The JaCoCo Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html).

Comment: This is just about generating code coverage report, it did not solve the question asked.

Comment: I still only see the androidTest folder and not the one for unit tests