# JaCoCo test coverage Could not determine the dependencies of task ':createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-experimental

I have following problem during execution of 'gradle createDebugCoverageReport':

> What went wrong:
>   Could not determine the dependencies of task ':createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport'.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
>
> Try:
>   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> Exception is:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.resolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:55)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.addToTaskGraph(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:139)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getJavaSourceFoldersForCoverage(BaseVariantData.java:682)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.coverage.JacocoReportTask$ConfigAction.lambda$execute$3(JacocoReportTask.java:335)
    at org.gradle.util.GUtil.uncheckedCall(GUtil.java:401)
```

I've tried all of the hints from: [How do I get a jacoco coverage report using Android gradle plugin 0.10.0 or higher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795595/how-do-i-get-a-jacoco-coverage-report-using-android-gradle-plugin-0-10-0-or-high). The only difference is that I'm using the experimental gradle plugin in version 0.8.3.

```
buildscript {

  repositories {

      jcenter()
      maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
  }

  dependencies {

      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.3'
  }
}

allprojects {

  repositories {

    jcenter()
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
apply plugin: "jacoco"

model {

  android {
      compileSdkVersion 25
      buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

      defaultConfig {

        applicationId ...
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel 21
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 25

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      }

      buildTypes {
          ...
          debug {

            debuggable true
            testCoverageEnabled true
          }
      }

      testOptions.unitTests {
           returnDefaultValues = true
      }
  }

  android.sources {
    ...
    test {
        java {
            source {
                srcDir "UnitTests"
            }
        }
    }

    androidTest {
        java {
            source {
                srcDir "AutomationTests"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  ...
}
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: post relevant code

Comment: What version of Gradle is used here?

Comment: I've missed all NDK, Crashlytics, release buildType and android.sources.main gradle configuration. I have also tried to use different jacoco versions without a success.

Comment: I'm using gradle 2.14.1